# What does the command system:update:finish do?

Tags: shopware6

The Shopware 6 `bin/console` command `system:update:finish` is used in the composer post-install and post-update scripts[[1]](https://github.com/shopware/production/blob/334cd5dc0878fca69b66e3de5fbd185aea91abe1/composer.json#L24-L32). When I look up the help for the command it does not give me any description of what the command does or when to use it:

```
$ bin/console system:update:finish --help
Usage:
  system:update:finish

Options:
  -h, --help            Display help for the given command. When no command is given display help for the list command
  -q, --quiet           Do not output any message
  -V, --version         Display this application version
      --ansi|--no-ansi  Force (or disable --no-ansi) ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction  Do not ask any interactive question
  -e, --env=ENV         The Environment name. [default: "prod"]
      --no-debug        Switch off debug mode.
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug
```

The official documentation does not provide any description either[[2]](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/resources/references/core-reference/commands-reference#system).

What does the command do? When should it be used, or should it be used only in the composer scripts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially this commands runs two other CLI commands internally:

```bash
bin/console database:migrate core --all
bin/console assets:install
```

It also dispatches `UpdatePostFinishEvent` and there are [a few different subscribers](https://github.com/search?q=UpdatePostFinishEvent%20user%3Ashopware%20repo%3Ashopware%2Fplatform%20path%3A%2Fsrc&type=Code&ref=advsearch&l=&l=) that listen to it.